# How can I run my own tor node or hop?

Tags: node

I want to run my own tor node/hop and may be use it as an exit node. Do you have any information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need a step by step to run a relay on Windows](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/16441/need-a-step-by-step-to-run-a-relay-on-windows)

Comment: Well, describe your case a bit more broad - and let's start! What the hardware do you have? ISP connection type and speed?

Answer (score -1):

Tor is for the most part a Remotely operated Network........using hosting services which essentially grant all governments backdoors.  They carried out hundreds of Raids early on in Tor's life to kill it.

However you can choose a hosting service either within the spehere of Russia or within the spehere of Nato.  Sweden and Switerland are so called Neutrals, but hosting services are more expensive.  Nato hosting comes cheap, Russian hosting comes hard to figure out.

First find out which country you would like to remotely host your Tor Exit Node.  Then search for hosting services within that Nation.