# How to install a Tor relay on windows as a service?

Tags: configuration, relays, tor-install

How do you install Tor to run as a middle relay on windows? And how do you make it start automaticly as a service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need a step by step to run a relay on Windows](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/16441/need-a-step-by-step-to-run-a-relay-on-windows)